# VB.NET Run command against 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, join, text

I have read 2 text files into 2 arrays and simply want to run a command which uses the 2 arrays.

Example:

```
part1.txt(array 1)
hxxp://somethinghere.com\1
hxxp://somethinghere.com\2

part2.txt(array 2)
Bob
James


myprogram.exe hxxp://somethinghere.com\1 Bob
myprogram.exe hxxp://somethinghere.com\2 James
```

I simply want to run a for loop which goes through both arrays, here's what I have so far:

```
Dim part1() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\part1.txt")
Dim part2() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\part2.txt")

For Each line As String In part1
    MsgBox(line)
Next
```

EDIT:
Working code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim part1() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\part1.txt")
    Dim part2() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\part2.txt")

    For parse As Integer = 0 To part1.GetUpperBound(0)
        MsgBox(String.Concat("myprog.exe " & """" & part1(parse) & """" & " -arg1 " & """" & part2(parse) & ".txt" & """"))
    Next
End Sub
```

So it will look like this:

myprog.exe "hxxp://somethinghere.com" -arg1 "Bob.txt"

Comment: Which part is it that you have problems with; running a command, or using array items as parameters?

Comment: Both parts essentially, I have already read the text files into an array, now I want to run a for loop against both arrays together, so the command uses the first line for array 1 and array 2, then it uses the second line from array 1 and array 2 and so on until finished.

Comment: Ok, then you need some code to actually run the program too... I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
 Private Sub testMethod()

        Dim part1() As String = New String() {"one", "two", "three"}
        Dim part2() As String = New String() {"10", "20", "30"}

        For parse As Integer = 0 To part1.GetUpperBound(0)
            Debug.Print(String.Concat("command ", part1(parse), part2(parse)))
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: This worked a treat, see my main post for the final version, thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx):

> **Enumerable.Zip(Of TFirst, TSecond, TResult) Method**
>
> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

So you could so something like

```
Dim part1() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\part1.txt")
Dim part2() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\part2.txt")

For Each element In part1.Zip(part2, Function(a, b) New With {a, b})
    MsgBox(String.Format("{0} - {1}", element.a, element.b))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that the arrays are the same length, then you can loop the indexes of one array and access the corresponding item in the other array.

To run the program you can use a `ProcessStartInfo` object to specify the parameters:

```
Dim part1() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\part1.txt")
Dim part2() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\part2.txt")

If part1.Length = part2.Length Then    
  For i As Integer = 0 To part1.Length - 1
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    p.FileName = "myprog.exe";
    p.Arguments = """" & part1(i) & """ -arg1 """ & part2(i) & ".txt"""
    Process.Start(p);
  Next
Else
  ' Oops! different number of items in the files
  ' Tell the user
End If
```

You can set more properties in the `ProcessStartInfo` object to control how the program is started.